# AWS S3 copy files from one bucket to other using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, airflow

I am planning to use AWS Python SDK (Boto3) to copy files from one bucket to other. Below is the same code I got from AWS documentation :

```
dest_object.copy_from(CopySource={
                'Bucket': self.object.bucket_name,
                'Key': self.object.key
            })
```

My question is how do I trigger this code and where should I deploy this code?
I originally thought of Lambda function but I am looking for alternate options in case Lambda times out for larger files ( 1 TB etc.).

Can I use Airflow to trigger this code somehow? may be invoke through Lambda ? Looking for suggestions from AWS experts.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what would 'trigger' this copy of files? For example, is it a one-off activity, or once per day? Do you want to copy _all_ files in the bucket or just a specific file? Are you copying all _new_ files that appear in the bucket? This information will help us to recommend an appropriate solution.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I need to copy all new files which appears in source bucket . FYI in the same code I am also planning to add delete functionality to delete the file from source bucket once it is copied in destination bucket.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to copy new files to another bucket is to use [Amazon S3 Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html). It will automatically copy new objects to the selected bucket, no code required.

However, this will not meet your requirement of deleting the incoming file after it is copied. Therefore, you should **create an AWS Lambda function and add a S3 trigger**. This will trigger the Lambda function whenever an object is created in the bucket.

The Lambda function should:

- Extract the bucket and object name from the `event` parameter
- Copy the object to the target bucket
- Delete the original object

The code would look something like:

```py
import boto3
import urllib

TARGET_BUCKET = 'target_bucket' # Change this

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

    # Loop through each incoming object
    for record in event['Records']:

        # Get incoming bucket and key
        source_bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        source_key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'])

        # Copy object to different bucket
        copy_source = {
            'Bucket': source_bucket,
            'Key': source_key
        }
        s3_resource.Bucket(TARGET_BUCKET).Object(source_key).copy(copy_source)

        # Delete original object
        s3_resource.Bucket(source_bucket).Object(source_key).delete()
```

The copy process is unlikely to approach the 15-minute limit of AWS Lambda, but it is worth testing on large objects.